# Strange behaviour with AJAX/jQuery and Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I think the best way to check the problem is to [visit](http://www.gabbatracklistworld.com/index.php?explore=test) it :

Opening the page, it should load the line in the bottom *Alptraum - La Vie Fascinante D'Une Jeune Vierge Effarouchee Marnaise - Unknown Date* thanks to this jQuery script :

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "list/browse_ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#browseList').html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#browseList').html("Error");
    }
});
```

on the server, it reply with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.lists').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        });

        $('.lists').mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        });                 
    });
</script>       

<div class="lists">                                 
    <a class="lblackb" href="index.php?explore=view&trackid=888"><?=htmlentities("Alptraum - La Vie Fascinante D'Une Jeune Vierge Effarouchee Marnaise - Unknown Date", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")?></a>
</div>
```

with this *lists* class :

```
.lists{width:710px; float:left; border-bottom:1px #000000 solid;}
```

and this is the *browseList* div :

```
.content{width:710px; float:left; color:#000000; font-weight:normal; text-align:left; margin-left:13px; margin-right:13px;}    
<div class="content" id="browseList">&nbsp;</div>
```

But how you can see, until you don't go on the div with the mouse (applying the jQuery mouseover/out effect), you can see the whole Line (at least, when I load the page I only see a small part as *Vierge Effarouchee Marnaise - Unknown Date*.

This happens to me only with Chrome (8.0.552.237)

Why this? And how can I fix this trouble? Thanks

P.S. This happens only if I wrote 1 line in the *#browseList'* div (with `.html()`). So for example if I just add a `<br/>` before or after that line, this doesnt happens :O

P.S.2. I've also notice that If i refresh the page many times, sometimes it appair OK, sometimes with the problem... really STRANGE! I think it's a Chrome bug...

Comment: Check and see if it happens too when providing a height or min-height for the containers

Comment: Do you mean on `content` div? Tried with `height:40px;` or `min-height:20px;` but nothing changes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you div class **lists** do not need

```
 float: left; /* delete this line */
```

Comment: In fact removing this attribute the problem vanish. But why?

Comment: Uhm..in fact I use these div in others space of my web application, but this problem happens only when I load them with AJAX. Can you give to me any further tips?